# Setting up SSL certificate(s) for a multi-service project (single domain)

Tags: docker, ssl, .net-core

Having recently acquired a .dev-domain, I'm trying to move my application over to this domain. However, .dev domains require a ssl-certificate to function (I can `curl` and get a response, but browsers will fail).

I have manually acquired a certificate (in .pem) using certbot, but I'm not sure where/how I need to apply/reference this certificate.

ALL OBJECTS BELOW ARE RUNNING IN DOCKER-CONTAINERS ON A RASPBERRY PI 4

My setup (All currently HTTP only):

- A .NET Core Gateway (Ocelot) (P: 7000)
- A React-Frontend (Nginx) (P: 8080)
- A File/Media-Server (Nginx) (P: 8082)
- A .NET Core WebApi (P: 5555)
- A MariaDB Database (P: 3300, only referenced by the API)

All incoming traffic is routed through the gateway, with:

- /api/... -> webapi
- /images/... -> fileserver
- /files/... -> fileserver
- /... -> React FrontEnd

Where do I need to add/reference my SSL-certificate? (And how do I go about doing this?)

Answer (score 1):

Since everything is routed through the Core Gateway based on the path, the TLS needs to be terminated at the Core Gateway. Otherwise the Gateway could not access the path and thus could not route by path. This means that the certificate should be applied there. Everything else should not be directly accessible from outside, but only through the gateway.

Comment: Would you happen to have any docs I can use for setting up SSL with Ocelot in .NET Core?
I've added `UseHsts` and `UseHTTPSRedirection`, but it seems to be refusing my connection (and I also have no idea where to hook in my .pem cert)